# How do I compose a regex from multiple regex-en with boost

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm writing a date parser using boost regex and I remember (vaguely) that boost allows regex composition. As an example of what I'm seeking here is sample code in Perl:

```perl
my $year     = qr/\d{1,4}(?:\d\(?B\.C\.\)?)?/;
my $gmonth   = qr/(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)/i;
my $fmonth   = qr/(?:VEND|BRUM|FRIM|NIVO|PLUV|VENT|GERM|FLOR|PRAI|MESS|THER|FRUC|COMP)/i;
my $hmonth   = qr/(?:TSH|CSH|KSL|TVT|SHV|ADR|ADS|NSN|IYR|SVN|TMZ|AAV|ELL)/i;
my $month    = qr/(?:$gmonth|$fmonth|$hmonth)/i;
my $day      = qr/\d{1,4}/;
my $DE       = qr/(?:\@\#DHEBREW\@|\@\#DROMAN\@|\@\#DFRENCH_R\@|\@\#DGREGORIAN\@|\@\#DJULIAN\@|\@\#DUNKNOWN\@)/;
my $DR       = qr/(?:AFT|BEF)\s/i;
my $DA       = qr/(?:ABT|CAL|EST)\s/i;
my $DI       = qr/INT\s/i;
my $prefix   = qr/(?:$DR|$DA|$DI)/i;
my $date     = qr/$prefix?(?:$DE\s)?(?:$day\s)?(?:$month\s)?$year/;
my $date_p   = qr/FROM\s$date\sTO\s$date/i;
my $date_f   = qr/FROM\s$date/i;
my $date_t   = qr/TO\s$date/i;
my $date_r   = qr/BET\.?\s$date\s(?:AND|-)\s$date/i;
my $GED_date = qr/(?:$date|$date_p|$date_r|$date_f|$date_t)/;

while (<DATA>) {
    next if /DATE\s$GED_date/;
    print $_;
}
```

As you can see composition is pretty much required. And this to just produce a regex to test for 'legality'. So my question is pretty much how might I do a similar sort of thing using boost? Pointers or links would be good. Small examples that I can extrapolate from would be excellent. In the mean time I'll continue to hit the boost books!

Comment: Perhaps can this page help you: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.grammars_and_nested_matches.building_a_grammar

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Spot on! A question though---is it possible to specify my sub-expressions is something a little less opaque than the expressive style?

Comment: The section "[Dynamic Regex Grammars](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.grammars_and_nested_matches.dynamic_regex_grammars)" in xpressive's docs show you how to build grammars using dynamic (string-based) regexes that refer to other regexes, which is maybe more like what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DEFINE syntax as in pcre. See this page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html 
(The last line of *Conditional Expressions*)

Example:

```
(?x)
(?(DEFINE)(?<gmonth>(?i)(?:JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)))
(?(DEFINE)(?<fmonth>(?i)(?:VEND|BRUM|FRIM|NIVO|PLUV|VENT|GERM|FLOR|PRAI|MESS|THER|FRUC|COMP)))
(?(DEFINE)(?<hmonth>(?i)(?:TSH|CSH|KSL|TVT|SHV|ADR|ADS|NSN|IYR|SVN|TMZ|AAV|ELL)))
(?(DEFINE)(?<month>\k<gmonth>|\k<fmonth>|\k<hmonth>))
```

Comment: Perfect! Only thing better than N languages is N+M languages!

Comment: Sure, it is revolutionary.